# Create a dynamic SideNav Widget with 2 models

Tags: yii2

What is the correct way to dynamically create a menu using the "SideNav Widget" and 2 models:

**category** (id, description)

**subcat** (id, category_id, description)

**EDIT**

What I have:

```
   $item = [];
    $Category = Category::find()->all();
    foreach($Category as $model) {
        $item[] = ['label' => $model->description, 'url' => '#'];
        $Subcat = Subcat::find()->where("category_id=$model->id")->all();
        foreach($Subcat as $model2) {
            $item[] = ['label' => $model2->description, 'url' => '#'];
        }
    }

echo SideNav::widget([
    'items' => $item,
```

[image]

As I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I decided to use the extension "[yii2-menu](https://github.com/Patroklo/yii2-menu)". And met my need.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for somethings like this?

for the sideName sample a simple one

```
 $menuGiiItems[] = ['label' => Yii::t('app','Gii Generators'),  'icon' => 'th-list', 'url'=>Url::to(['/gii'])],

                ['label' => Yii::t('app','Generator 2'),  'url'=>Url::to(['/auth/item'])],
                ['label' => Yii::t('app','Generator 3'),  'url'=>Url::to(['auth/item-child'])],
                ['label' => Yii::t('app','Generator 4'), 'url'=>Url::to(['/auth/rule'])];
                $type = SideNav::TYPE_PRIMARY;
                $heading = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></i> ' . Yii::t('app',' Gii - Development Automation ');
                echo SideNav::widget([
                    'type' => $type,
                    'encodeLabels' => false,
                    'heading' => $heading,
                    'items' =>$menuGiiItems,
                ]);
```

or more complex one with nested item

```
        $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'DFenX - Yii2 User - '. Yii::t('app','Authentication manager'),  'icon' => 'user', 'items' => [
            ['label' => '/user/admin/index',       'icon' => 'list', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/admin/index'])],
            ['label' => '/user/1 (view)', 'icon' =>'eye-open', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/1'])],
            ['label' => 'Settings', 'icon' => 'cog', 'items' => [
                ['label' => '/user/settings', 'icon' => 'cog', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/settings'])],
                ['label' => '/user/settings/profile',  'url'=>Url::to(['/user/settings/profile'])],
                ['label' => '/user/settings/account',  'url'=>Url::to(['user/settings/account'])],
                ['label' => '/user/settings/networks', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/settings/networks'])],
            ]],
            ['label' => 'Registration', 'icon' => 'user', 'items' => [                                
                ['label' => '/user/registration/register', 'icon' => 'user', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/registration/register'])],
                ['label' => '/user/registration/resend', 'icon' => 'user', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/registration/resend'])],
            ]],
            ['label' => 'Security', 'icon' => 'user', 'items' => [                                
                ['label' => '/user/security/login', 'icon' => 'user', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/security/login'])],
                ['label' => '/user/security/logout', 'icon' => 'user', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/security/logout'])],
            ]],
            ['label' => 'Recovery', 'icon' => 'user', 'items'  => [                               
                ['label' => '/user/recovery/request', 'icon' => 'user', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/recovery/request'])],
                ['label' => '/user/recovery/reset', 'icon' => 'user', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/recovery/reset'])],
            ]],
        ]];

        $type = SideNav::TYPE_PRIMARY;
        $heading = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i> ' . Yii::t('app','AUTHENTICATION');
        //$heading = ['label' => 'Books', 'icon' => 'book'] ;                
        echo SideNav::widget([
            'type' => $type,
            'encodeLabels' => false,
            'heading' => $heading,
            'items' =>$menuItems,
        ]);
```

Comment: Yes, but how loop the 2 models ?

Comment: I do not get... :(  look my EDIT2

Comment: I have update the answer with a more complex menu  with nested item and sub level

Comment: i need a dynamic menu. This one are a static menu

Comment: What mean dinamic.Server side you can generate dinamically the equivalent code...`<?php  echo "['label' => '/user/settings', 'icon' => 'cog', 'url'=>Url::to(['/user/settings'])]," ?>`

Comment: I have to make a loop in the CATEGORY model and then another loop in SUBCAT model .

That part I'm not getting.

Comment: Get The parent model, the in the outer loop get the child model and finally echo the value you need for generate an equivalent code......

Comment: Hmm.. I need to ride the menu with the values that are on the database. See images to better understand

Comment: yes for this you need to get the parent model and in the loop based on this result get the childs model ...

Comment: Okay, I'm almost there ... How do a loop (to get the subcat) within the first loop?

Comment: I have update the aswer with a sample fo nested loop

Comment: hi, @scaisEdge, its show: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ']'

Comment: Yes it's wrong i deleted it and i think a better solution for nested loop

Comment: Did you have any idea? @scaisEdge

Comment: I need a few day for find the right solution. Essentially, in the inner loop, it comes to finding a way to assign values dynamically read to a variable that better complements the part of the array relative to these menu items. I can not find an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$item = [];
    $Category = Category::find()->all();
    $count=0;
    foreach($Category as $model) {
        $item[] = ['label' => $model->description, 'url' => '#'];
        $Subcat = Subcat::find()->where("category_id=$model->id")->all();
        $cnt=0;
        foreach($Subcat as $model2) {
            $item[$count]['items'][$cnt] = ['label' => $model2->description, 'url' => '#'];
            $cnt++;
        }
        $count++;
    }

    echo SideNav::widget([
    'items' => $item,
    )];
```